# Suggest most optimized way using hive or pig

Tags: hive, apache-pig

Problem Statement
Assume there is one text file of logs. Below are the fields in the file.

Log File

```
userID
productID
action
```

Where Action would be one of these –

```
Browse, Click, AddToCart, Purchase, LogOut
```

Select users who performed AddToCart action but did not perform Purchase action.

```
('1001','101','201','Browse'),
('1002','102','202','Click'),
('1001','101','201','AddToCart'),
('1001','101','201','Purchase'),
('1002','102','202','AddToCart')
```

Can anyone suggest to get this info using hive or pig with optimised performance

Comment: There are 4 columns in your sample data but you mention that the log file has 3 columns.

Comment: Lots of information missing. For example, is your data actually in hive tables?  Most importantly, what have you actually tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to do using sum() or analytical sum() depending on exact requirements in a single table scan. What if User added to cart two products, but purchased only one?

For User+Product:

```
select userID, productID 
  from
(
select 
       userID,
       productID,
       sum(case when action='AddToCart' then 1 else 0 end) addToCart_cnt,
       sum(case when action='Purchase' then 1 else 0 end)  Purchase_cnt
  from table
  group by userID, productID
)s
where addToCart_cnt>0 and Purchase_cnt=0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hive**: Use `not in`

```
select * from table 
where action='AddtoCart' and 
      userID not in (select distinct userID from table where action='Purchase')
```

**Pig**: Filter the ids using action and do a left join and check id is null

```
A = LOAD '\path\file.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (userID:int,b:int,c:int,action:chararray) -- Note I am assuming the first 3 columns are int.You will have to figure out the loading without the quotes.
B = FILTER A BY (action='AddToCart');
C = FILTER A BY (action='Purchase');
D = JOIN B BY userID LEFT OUTER,C BY userID;
E = FILTER D BY C.userID is null;
DUMP E;
```